# default.aspx file, is there a way to create versions?

Tags: site, versioning, collection

i have default.aspx file in the main site collection w/c is our landing page. Is there any way it can have versioning so its easier for me to go back to previous edits/versions?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be versioned.

You can use a new page in the Pages or Site Pages library that will be versioned. You can set this as the site home page in the ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Is there a "redirect" way so that when users try to go to https://mycompany067.sharepoint.com, it will point to landingpage.aspx which is in the "Pages" or "Sites Pages" folder?

my intent is that users will just need to remember "https://mycompany067.sharepoint.com" to hit the landing page.

Comment: Whatever is set as the homepage is where they will land if they only type tenant.sharepoint.com. If landingpage.aspx is set as your home page, then that's where they will end up no matter where it is stored. If they hit tenant.sharepoint.com/default.aspx, directly it won't, you'll have to drop some javascript on the page to redirect to the desired page.

Comment: do you have a sample javascript that will redirect from default.aspx to the  landingpage.aspx?

Comment: Look up window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

You can't version this page, but if you create a new one you can configure the library in which this new one is in to have versioning.

> Library Settings > Versioning > Configure as you prefer